# Java Swing Application - Lauch4j version error

Tags: java, swing, version, desktop-application, launch4j

I am making a Java Application using Java Swing and Jframe with a external video library . I am using window 11 JDK 19.0.2 . I want to create standalone application I tried using Launch4j but it is giving version conflict. Window 11 and this version of Java dont come with JRE seperatly how can create portable standalone project

I had JRE version 17 so I downgraded Java version 17 I am still getting error

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.example.swing.panel.Panel
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/example/swing/panel/Panel has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 63.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0
```

I tried intalling java 17 create JAVA HOME path but same error. My system still shows Java 19

Comment: Your `Panel` class was compiled with Java 19.  You cannot run the `Panel` class with Java 17.  You have to compile all your classes with Java 17.  By the way, naming your classes the same as JRE classes (`java.awt.Panel`) will cause you multiple problems in the future.  Always name your classes differently.

Comment: I degraded my Java to version 17 and compiled the the classes as well , still getting same  issue .